# Having trouble sending HTML form to email through PhP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have created a form and would like the information to be sent to my email using php. The information submits, and I receive an e-mail, but the email only displays the first and last name of input by the individual submitting the form. I would like to know what is missing from either the php side or html side.

Thank You

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="appraisal_form.php">

<table width="500px">

<tr>
<td>
     <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
 <td>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
    <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>

<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td>
    <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td>
    <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>


<!--- Property Type-->

<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="lender">Lender *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="lender" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <label for="loan_officer">Loan Officer *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="loan_officer" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="property_address">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="property_address" maxlength="100" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="city">City *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="city" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="zip">Zip Code *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="zip" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="pin">PIN(Permenant Index Number) *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="pin" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="rooms">Number of Rooms *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="rooms" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="bath">Number of Bathrooms *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="bath" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<!--- Garage /yes or no-->
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="plat">Plat of Survey *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="plat" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="borrow">Borrowers Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="borrow" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<!--- sale /refinance-->
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="price">Purchase Price *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="price" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="loan_amount">Loan Amount *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="loan" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <label for="cod">C.O.D *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="cod" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <label for="invoice">Invoice *</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <input  type="text" name="invoice" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td> 
<td>
    <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">   
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="reset">
 </td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

PHP

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$lender = $_POST['lender']; // required

$loan_officer = $_POST['loan_officer']; // required

$property_address = $_POST['property_address']; // required

$city = $_POST['city']; // required

$zip = $_POST['zip']; // not required

$pin = $_POST['pin']; // required

$rooms = $_POST['rooms']; // required

$bath = $_POST['bath']; // required

$plat = $_POST['plat']; // required

$borrow = $_POST['borrow']; // not required

$price = $_POST['price']; // required

$cod = $_POST['cod']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required


$to = "rosaliam2@yahoo.com";

$subject = "New Appraisal Request";


$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.           <br />';

}


mail($to, $subject, $message, "From" . $first_name . $last_name); 
echo "Your Information has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$message`?

Comment: i see what you're saying , i need to just go back and see what i did,

Comment: Of course. You just have to compose the email body in `$message` with the data from the form fields. For starters try `$message = print_r($_POST, true);` just to check everything is ok.

Comment: where am i putting 
   ` $message = print_r($_POST, true);`  in a developer or in the actual code

Comment: Fixed it! 
my only other problem is i used some radio inputs and they do not show up in the message 
`<tr> <td> <lable=for"refinance"> Sale or Refinance *</label> </td> <td><input type="radio" name="refinance" value="refinance">Refinance <input type="radio" name="refinance" value="sale">Sale </td> </tr> `


what would i put in my php to grab the value? 

`$email_message .= "Sale or Refinance: ".clean_string($refinance)."\n";`

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no message variable to send!!
you are just sending $first_name and $last_name as headers!

Comment: fixed it! 


my only other problem is i used some radio inputs and they do not show up in the message

`<tr>
 <td>
  <lable=for"refinance"> Sale or Refinance *</label>
 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="refinance" value="refinance">Refinance
<input type="radio" name="refinance" value="sale">Sale
</td>
</tr>`



what would i put in my php to grab the value?

 `$email_message .= "Sale or Refinance: ".clean_string($refinance)."\n";`